# Как обрезать текст после второго указанного символа

Tags: c#

есть к примеру `string text = "Orlan_aver"` либо он может быть `string text = "Orlan_01_aver"`
Как мне обрезать текст после второго нижнего подчёркивания? Понятно что количество их можно узнать через `foreach(char s in text)` а вот что делать когда их 2, понятия не имею. Нужно чтобы в конечном итоге когда подчёркивание было одно, оставалось к примеру Orlan, а когда два Orlan_01 (Тоесть _aver нужно удалить, но оно может также менятся, например на _lev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `LastIndexOf`

```
string text = "Orlan_aver";
Console.WriteLine(text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf("_")));

text = "Orlan_01_aver";
Console.WriteLine(text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf("_")));
```

Вывод

```
Orlan
Orlan_01
```